# Veins Multiple Applications in multiples Vehicle types

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

in my simulation using OMNeT++, Veins, and SUMO i want run multiple applications according to their vehicle type, as specified in the `.rou.xml` file using `type="XXX"`

For example:

- `<vehicle ...  type="private" ... >` runs `APP_private` (using something like `*.node[*].applType ="APP_private"`)
- `<vehicle ... type="bus" ... >` runs `APP_bus` (using something like `*.node[*].applType ="APP_bus"`)

How can I define this in `omnetpp.ini`?

Answer (score 4):

Veins 4.6 allows you to set any or all of the `moduleType`, `moduleName`, and `moduleDisplayString` parameters not just to a string (which will set the OMNeT++ module type, module name, and module display string to instantiate for every vehicle driving in the configured region of interest, respectively):

You can also set the `moduleType`, `moduleName`, and `moduleDisplayString` parameters to what Veins calls a [mapping](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.6/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManager.cc#L189). This will use different parameter values for different SUMO vehicle types.

The full details can be found in the source code [here](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.6/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManager.cc#L106) or on the Veins website. Here's the short version:

- `"a"`          : assign value `"a"` to all nodes (for backward compatibility)
- `"a=b`        : assign value `"b"` to vehicle type `"a"`. the presence of any other vehicle type in the simulation will cause the simulation to stop
- `"a=b c=d`    : assign value `"b"` to vehicle type `"a"` and `"d"` to `"c"`. the presence of any other vehicle type in the simulation will cause the simulation to stop
- `"a=b c=d *=e"`: everything which is not of vehicle type `"a"` or `"b"`, assign value `"e"`

A module type of `"0"` means to not instantiate this module.

In your specific case, it seems like it should be sufficient to use `*.manager.moduleName = "XXX=busNode *=node"` and to configure `*.busNode[*].applType = "APP_bus"` and `*.node[*].applType = "APP_private"`.

Comment: How can I customize this applType ?

Comment: As https://stackoverflow.com/a/51052729/4707703 points out, depending on the Veins version, `moduleType` might need to explicitly set types for both `XXX` and `*`, too

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue. I tried to set the modulename as Christoph's answer but the I got the following error: "keys of mappings of moduleType and moduleName are not the same" It seems that the Veins mapping feature maps a veins moduleType "org.car2x.veins.nodes.Car" to a veins module name.

However, I managed to solve this error by defining a veins module to match the same keys, so the final omnetpp.ini setting would be:

```
*.manager.moduleType = "XXX=org.car2x.veins.nodes.Car *=org.car2x.veins.nodes.Car"
*.manager.moduleName = "XXX=busNode *=node"
*.busNode[*].applType = "APP_bus"
*.node[*].applType = "APP_private"
```

Comment: Does this function the same way in inet ? or just veins?