# Different Models in Veins

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I've been searching several simulators for moving vehicles and I've found **Veins**. I was wondering if it's possible to create different models of the vehicles simulated. I mean by that is it possible to create a different type/change the properties of vehicles to create a custom simulation with custom parameters/scenario and custom vehicles?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47515408/veins-multiples-applications-in-multiples-vehicles-types/51052729#51052729