# Communication between a car and a pedestrian in Veins

Tags: veins, sumo

I would like to know how could I create a wireless communication between a car and a pedestrian (V2P) in Veins?
Thanks a for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Veins allows to specify a module for a vehicle type it gets from SuMO: [Veins Multiple Applications in multiples Vehicle types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47515408/veins-multiples-applications-in-multiples-vehicles-types)

You have to setup your network and pedestrians according to the [SuMO wiki](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Simulation/Pedestrians) and then configure the corresponding module in Veins.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Julian. I have SUMO properly configured to run both vehicles and pedestrians. But I am still confused after your answer. Veins has a specific module to handle pedestrians or should I create it? Is there any example of code where I can see a pedestrian communicating with a car?

Comment: As of Veins 5a1, pedestrian mobility is not supported out of the box and needs additional code to be written. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54891688/4707703