# Pedestrian in veins (omnet++/sumo)

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I want to simulate a pedestrian simulation in Omnet++ from SUMO, using Veins.

I made all the steps suggested here [Pedestrian Simulation in veins (omnet++/sumo)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54829271/9659793) in the question part.
From the corresponding answer I got that, even if it's not supported in Veins, it is still possible to simulate pedestrian with Veins, but I didn't get how exactly.

Since I am not that confident with Omnet++ (at least not to play deeply with TraCI configuration files) and since it seems this was already done for "internal projects", is it possible to see draft files used in those projects for pedestrian subscription?

If not, which are in detail the implementation steps?